# How to do a staged rollout for my webapp?

Tags: amazon-web-services, devops

I have a web app which is served to multiple countries, let's say I release a new version 1.53 for example. How can I release that update to a subset of countries and after "x" amount of days roll it out for the rest of the globe? Is this possible with AWS alone or do I need to look at different technologies outside of AWS?

Edit:

My current stack for serving the app is:
I have an EC2 instance which has the app, I have an s3 that hosts some static files then finally I use route 53 to connect the app to my domain.

Answer (score 0):

There are ... *so* many ways to do this.   It really depends on what you're trying to do.

Right off the top of my head though, the "simplest" and "crudest" way would be via a crontab entry for a script to be executed every x days. that script could do any of the following:

- pull the next country to be rolled out and remove it from the list it came from (db, nosql, file, etc.)
- add (or uncomment) an entry to your http config to allow for `n` country to be made active
- update a table (db, nosql, file list, etc.) that marks a country as active.   the web app would poll this and only look for active countries
- etc. etc.... etc.

however, if you want to do it solely through aws and its control panel... well, i have no idea and this answer will not help at all =\

but, if you have access to your own server environment... it might be helpful after all =]